# D3 positioning a custom SVG on scattersplot

Tags: d3.js, svg, graph, data-visualization

I have a scatterplot working like I expect when adding simple svg circles to the chart. The circles appear in the correct positions.

When trying to duplicate this positioning with a custom SVG image using similar code, the illustrations are showing up but the coordinates are a little off. Im wondering if this has to do with the fact that I am trying to embed an SVG tag within another SVG and the viewbox values. The x and y attributes are being set properly on inspection, they are equal to the cx and cy values of the corresponding circles.

Code here
https://codepen.io/kylehagler/pen/VxPqyM

```
var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

/* 
 * value accessor - returns the value to encode for a given data object.
 * scale - maps value to a visual display encoding, such as a pixel position.
 * map function - maps from data value to display value
 * axis - sets up axis
 */

// setup x
var xValue = function(d) {
        return d.episode;
    },
    xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]),
    xMap = function(d) {
        return xScale(xValue(d));
    },
    xAxis = d3.svg
        .axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient('bottom');

// setup y
var yValue = function(d) {
        return d['year'];
    }, // data -> value
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]), // value -> display
    yMap = function(d) {
        return yScale(yValue(d));
    }, // data -> display
    yAxis = d3.svg
        .axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient('left')
        .ticks(5)
        .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

// add the graph canvas to the chart div
var svg = d3
    .select('#chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

// add the tooltip area to the webpage
var tooltip = d3
    .select('body')
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'tooltip')
    .style('opacity', 0);

var myData = [
    {
        episode: 1,
        type: 'book',
        title: 'The Crisis of the Old Order',
        author: 'Arthur Schlesinger Jr.',
        year: 1957,
        image: ''
    },
    {
        episode: 1,
        type: 'book',
        title: 'The View from Chivo',
        author: 'H. Allen Smith',
        year: 1971,
        image: ''
    },
    {
        episode: 1,
        type: 'book',
        title: 'The Peking Man is Missing',
        author: 'Claire Taschdjian',
        year: 1977,
        image: ''
    },
    {
        episode: 1,
        type: 'book',
        title: 'La Presidentia',
        author: 'Lois Gould',
        year: 1982,
        image: ''
    },
    {
        episode: 1,
        type: 'book',
        title: 'Masterpieces of World Literature in Digest Form',
        author: 'Frank Magill',
        year: 1952,
        image: ''
    },
    {
        episode: 3,
        type: 'book',
        title: "Lady Chatterly's Lover",
        author: 'D.H. Lawrence',
        year: 1928,
        image: ''
    },
    {
        episode: 4,
        type: 'book',
        title: 'Italy',
        author: 'Herbert Kubly',
        year: 1961,
        image: ''
    },
    {
        episode: 4,
        type: 'book',
        title: 'Nursery Friends from France',
        author: 'Olive Beaupre Miller',
        year: 1925,
        image: ''
    },
    {
        episode: 6,
        type: 'book',
        title: 'The Best of Everything',
        author: 'Rona Jaffe',
        year: 1958,
        image: ''
    },
    {
        episode: 6,
        type: 'book',
        title: 'Exodus',
        author: 'Leon Uris',
        year: 1958,
        image: ''
    },
    {
        episode: 8,
        type: 'book',
        title: 'Atlas Shrugged',
        author: 'Ayn Rand',
        year: 1957,
        image: ''
    }
];


// change string (from CSV) into number format
myData.forEach(function(d) {
  d.episode = +d.episode;
  d['year'] = +d['year'];
  //    console.log(d);
});

// don't want dots overlapping axis, so add in buffer to data domain
xScale.domain([d3.min(myData, xValue) - 1, 13]);
yScale.domain([d3.min(myData, yValue) - 1, d3.max(myData, yValue) + 1]);

// x-axis
svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
  .call(xAxis)
  .append('text')
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .attr('x', width)
  .attr('y', -6)
  .style('text-anchor', 'end')
  .text('episode');

// y-axis
svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .call(yAxis)
  .append('text')
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
  .attr('y', 6)
  .attr('dy', '.71em')
  .style('text-anchor', 'end')
  .text('year');

// draw dots
svg
  .selectAll('.dot')
  .data(myData)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'dot')
  .attr('r', 3.5)
  .attr('cx', xMap)
  .attr('cy', yMap)
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
  tooltip
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style('opacity', 0.9);
  tooltip
    .html(d['Cereal Name'] + '<br/> (' + xValue(d) + ', ' + yValue(d) + ')')
    .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 5 + 'px')
    .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 28 + 'px');
})
  .on('mouseout', function(d) {
  tooltip
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .style('opacity', 0);
});

// draw falling men
svg
  .selectAll('.fallingman')
  .data(myData)
  .enter()
  .append('svg')
  .attr('class', 'fallingman')
  .attr('viewBox', '0 0 960 700')
  .attr('width', '100')
  .attr('x', xMap)
  .attr('y', yMap)
  .append('path')
  .attr(
  'd',
  'M198 541.2c-.5-.5-.5-.9-.1-1.5 1.5-2.1 2.9-4.3 4.4-6.4.7-1 0-2.6-1.5-2.7-2.4-.2-4.7-.6-7.1.4-1.8.7-3.8 1.1-5.7 1.5-1.2.3-2.2-.3-2.1-1.3 0-.5.4-1.1.8-1.3 2-.9 4.1-1.6 6.2-2.4.5-.2 1-.4 1.5-.8.3-.3.5-.8.8-1.2-.4-.2-.9-.5-1.3-.6-.4-.1-.9.1-1.3.1l-5.7 1.2c-.6.1-1.1.4-1.7.6-1.1.4-1.9.2-2.3-.8-.4-1-.1-1.5 1.1-1.9 2.6-.8 5.1-1.4 7.7-2.2.5-.1 1.1-.2 1.5-.5s.6-.7.8-1.1c-.4-.2-.8-.7-1.2-.7-2.9-.1-5.8-.2-8.7.7-.8.2-1.4.1-1.6-.7-.2-.8.1-1.6 1-1.8 2.3-.5 4.5-1.2 6.8-1.3 3.2-.1 6.4.2 9.7.3.4 0 1.2-.2 1.3-.3.1-.7.3-1.6-.1-2.1-1.4-1.9-3.3-3.3-5.7-3.9-1.8-.5-2.8-1.7-3.5-3.3-.3-.7-.1-1.3.8-1.3s1.8 0 2.5.3c5.2 2.1 10.3 4.2 15.5 6.4 1.3.5 2.4 1.4 3.7 1.8 1.1.3 2.4.1 3.6-.1 1.1-.2 1.7.3 2.4 1.1 1.8 2.3 2.5 4.9 2.8 7.8v1.8c0 .7-.4 1-1.1 1.3-1.1.4-2.1 1-3 1.7-2.8 2.3-5.9 3.8-9.4 4.6-1.9.4-3.3 1.7-4.5 3.2-1.3 1.5-2.6 2.9-4 4.3-.5.5-1.2.9-1.8 1.3-.7-.2-1.1-.2-1.5-.2zm135.6-204c0 .4 0 .9-.1 1.3-.1 2.1 0 4.3-.5 6.3-.6 2.1-1.8 4-2.7 6-.4.8-.9 1.6-1.2 2.5-.5 1.4-.9 2.9-1.4 4.3-.1.4-.5.6-.8.9-.3-.3-.7-.7-.8-1-.2-.6-.1-1.3-.2-1.9-.4-2.8-.9-5.6-1.3-8.4 0-.2-.1-.3-.2-.4-.6-2.4-1.1-4.7-1.7-7.1-.7-2.8-1.2-5.5-1.2-8.4 0-.3-.2-.6-.2-.9-.6-2.3-1.2-4.5-1.8-6.8-.6-2.3-1.1-4.7-1.8-7.1-1.2-3.9-2.4-7.8-3.8-11.7-1.3-3.6-4.4-5-7.8-5.9-2.3-.6-4.3.6-6.3 1.3-1.2.4-2.2 1.3-3.3 2.1-1.7 1.2-3.6 2.2-5.2 3.6-2.1 1.8-4.4 2.7-7.1 2.6-2.2-.1-3.2-.9-3.6-3-.3-1.5-.2-3.1-1.1-4.5-.8-1.3-1.2-2.7-2-4-.8-1.4-2.2-2.3-3.6-3.1-2.2-1.3-5.2-.6-6.4 1.5-1.3 2.2-.8 4.7-.9 7.1-.2 4.4 1.6 8.6 2.1 12.9.2 1.9.9 3.8-.5 5.6-.2.2-.1.7-.1 1 .2 2.5.5 4.9.8 7.4.2 2 1.3 2.9 3.3 3 1.5.1 3 .3 4.4.2 1 0 2-.1 2.9-.5 1.9-.9 3.7-2.1 5.7-2.9 2.5-1 3.8-.2 3.7 2.6 0 1.4.4 2.7.8 4.1.4 1.6 1.1 3.2 1.3 4.8.4 4 .7 8 1 12 .1 1.9.3 3.8.4 5.7.1 1.9-2.8 4.1-4.6 3.5-.3-.1-.5-.3-.7-.6-.9-1-1.8-2-2.8-3-1.7-1.8-3.6-3.4-5.1-5.3-2.6-3.3-5.1-6.8-7.5-10.3-1.5-2.2-3-4.4-5.2-6-1.2-.8-2.3-1.7-3.4-2.6-.8-.7-1.4-1.5-2.1-2.3-1.3-1.3-2.7-2.5-3.8-4-1.6-2.2-2.6-4.6-3.5-7.2-2-5.9-4.2-11.8-6.4-17.6-.5-1.3-1-2.5-1.6-3.7-1.1-2.2-2.9-3.6-4.7-5.2-1.3-1.2-2.4-2.5-2.6-4.5-.3-2.6-.7-5.3-2-7.7-.6-1.1-.7-2.5-1.1-3.7-.1-.4-.4-1-.8-1.1-2-.5-2.4-2-2.5-3.6-.3-4.5-.4-8.9-.6-13.4 0-.5-.1-1-.2-1.5-.5-1.5-1.1-3-1.7-4.5-.6-1.4-2-2-3.5-1.6-3 1-5.8 2.3-8.3 4.3-3.2 2.6-4.9 5.8-3.9 9.9.4 1.8 1.1 3.5 1.8 5.3.5 1.3 1.1 2.5 1.7 3.7.8 1.7 1.6 3.4 2.6 4.9.6 1 .7 1.9.3 2.9-.2.5-.2 1.1 0 1.6.4 1.5.9 2.9 1.5 4.4.6 1.6 1.4 3.2 2.1 4.7.3.5.9.8 1.1 1.4.7 1.9 1.5 3.9 2 5.9.5 2.1.8 4.3 1.2 6.5.1.7.1 1.5.3 2.1 1.1 2.6 2.4 5 3.3 7.6 1 2.7 1.9 5.4 2.1 8.3.1 2 .8 4 1.4 6 .5 1.7 1.4 3.3 1.7 5.1.5 2.6.7 5.2 1.1 7.8.1.6.2 1.3.5 1.8 1.2 1.8 2.5 3.6 3.7 5.4 1.3 1.8 2.7 3.5 3.8 5.4.9 1.5 1.6 3.2 2.3 4.8 1 1.9 2 3.8 2.9 5.8 1 2.1 2.1 4.2 3.8 5.9.8.8.9 2 .3 2.6-1.1 1.4-1 2.9-1.1 4.4-.1 1.3-.1 2.8 1.1 3.9 1.2 1.1 2.4 2.2 3.5 3.4 2 2.1 4 4.2 6.1 6.2 3.1 3 6.4 5.7 9.2 9 2.9 3.3 5.2 7.1 7.8 10.7 1.6 2.2 3.2 4.5 4.9 6.7 2.3 2.8 4.8 5.4 7 8.2 2.3 3.1 3.2 6.7 3 10.5-.2 3.9-1.4 7.6-3 11.1-2.3 5-4.7 9.9-7.3 14.8-1.7 3.2-3.6 6.2-5.5 9.2-2.1 3.3-4.5 6.4-6.7 9.7-3.5 5.1-8.4 8.4-14.1 10.3-7.3 2.5-14.7 4.7-22.1 6.9-5 1.5-10.1 2.6-15.1 3.9-1.9.5-3.7.8-5.6 1.3-1.3.3-1.9 1.1-1.6 2.1.4 1.5 1.3.7 2.1.4 1.2-.4 2.6-.7 3.4.2 1.2 1.4 2.4 3 2.9 4.7 1 3.1 1.8 6.3 2.2 9.5.4 2.6 1 5.6-2.7 6.8-.8.3-.9 1.1-.1 1.6.5.3 1.1.6 1.6.6 1-.1 2.1-.4 3.1-.7 1.8-.6 3.5-1.4 5.2-2.1 13.2-5.2 26.7-9.4 39.3-16.1 3.5-1.9 6.9-3.8 10.3-5.9 2.6-1.6 4.9-3.4 7.4-5.1 2.3-1.6 4.6-3.2 6.8-4.9 2.8-2.1 5.6-4.3 8.4-6.5 3.1-2.4 5.9-5.1 7.9-8.4 1.1-1.8 2.4-3.6 3.7-5.3 2.6-3.3 6-5.6 9.5-7.8 1-.6 2-1.2 3.1-1.4 2.6-.5 5.2-.7 7.8-1.1.5-.1.9-.2 1.4-.4.8-.3 1.6-.7 2.4-1 1.2-.5 1.5-.2 2.1 1 .4.8 1 1.6 1.6 2.2.3.3 1 .3 1.4.6 2.3 2 4.4 4.2 7.2 5.6 1.7.9 3.3 2 5.4 1.9 1.8-.1 3.7 0 5.5 0 2.7 0 4.9-1 7-2.6 2.6-2 4.9-4.3 6.4-7.3 1.5-2.9 1.6-6 1.2-9.1-.2-1.5-.1-3.1-1.1-4.5-1-1.3-2-2.7-2.8-4.1-.3-.5-.4-1.5-.1-1.9 1.1-1.4 2.4-2.6 3.7-3.8 1.8-1.5 3.8-2.9 5.6-4.4 1.6-1.3 3.3-2.5 4.9-3.8 1.8-1.3 3.6-2.5 5.4-3.8s3.6-2.5 5.5-3.7c1.6-1 2.8-2.2 3.5-3.9.4-1.1.7-2.2 1.2-3.3 1-2.3 2-4.6 3.7-6.4 2.3-2.3 3.4-5.1 3.6-8.2.4-4.5 1.8-8.7 3.1-12.9 1-3.6 2.5-7 3.7-10.6.7-2.1 1.1-4.3 1.7-6.4.4-1.5 1.1-2.9 1.6-4.4.7-2.3.1-3.7-1.8-5.2-1.2-.9-2.4-1.7-3.8-2.3-2.6-1-5.2-2.1-8.1-2.2-.9-.1-1.5.3-1.8 1.2-.9 2.6-1.8 5.2-2.6 7.8-.4 1.1-.8 2.3-1.1 3.4-.8 2.8-1.6 5.7-2.2 8.5-.6 2.7-1.2 5.3-2.7 7.6-.9 1.3-1.8 2.7-2.5 4.2-.9 2.2-2 4.1-3.8 5.7-1.9 1.7-3.7 3.3-6.5 2.6-1.5-.3-2.9-.7-4.4-.8-4.2-.3-8.4-.8-12.3-2.4-1.7-.7-3.1-1.9-3.7-3.5-1-2.8-1.6-5.7-2.4-8.6s-1.5-5.9-2.3-8.8c-.3-1-.7-2-1.1-3-.6-1.2-1.2-2.4-1.9-3.7-1.2-2.4-2.3-5-3.7-7.3-1.7-2.8-3.5-5.6-5.5-8.2-2.5-3.3-5.3-6.5-8-9.6-2.6-2.9-5.1-5.9-6.3-9.7-.1-.3-.4-.6-.6-.9.5.1.3.1.2.2zm-3.6 48.5c2.7 1.4 4.9 3.6 7 5.6 1.7 1.7 3.3 3.5 5.4 4.7 2 1.2 4.5 1.8 6.8 2.5 1.6.5 3.2.9 4.8 1.4.9.3 1.7.6 2.6.8 1.5.4 2.2 1.3 2.1 2.8-.2 4.1.3 8.1 1.4 12 1.3 4.8 2.7 9.5 4 14.3.6 2.2 1.1 4.5 1.7 6.8-2.7-.3-4.9-2.2-5.6-4.4-.3-.9-.8-1.8-1.3-2.7-.5-.7-2.1-.8-2.8-.1-.8.7-1.6.8-2.6.5-3-.7-5.9-1.4-8.8-2.1-1-.2-1.9-.6-2.1-1.7-.2-1.6-1.2-2.7-2.3-3.4-1.5-1-2.2-2.4-2.8-3.9-1.7-4.2-3.3-8.5-4.9-12.7-1.3-3.5-2.7-7.1-3.9-10.7-1.2-3.4-2.1-6.9-2.6-10.5.1-.1.2-.3.3-.4 1.2.4 2.5.6 3.6 1.2zm-8.4 9.9c1.3 3.8 2.6 7.5 4.3 11.1 2.2 4.6 4.8 8.9 8.1 12.8.8.9 1.6 1.7 2.3 2.7.3.5.3 1.3.3 1.9 0 .9-.2 1.8-.1 2.7 0 1.2-.2 2.2-.8 3.4-.7 1.2-1.4 2.5-.9 4.2.3 1.1 0 2.3.1 3.5.1 1.5.2 3 .3 4.6-1.3-.3-2.1-.8-2.5-2-1.3-3.1-2.7-6.2-4.1-9.3-1.4-3-2.9-6-4.4-9-1.2-2.3-3.1-3.9-5.2-5.3l-13.8-9c-.8-.5-1.6-1.1-2.4-1.5-1.6-.8-1.7-2.6-2.6-3.8-1.3-1.9-2.8-3.8-4.3-5.6-.5-.6-.6-1-.1-1.6.4-.5.7-1.2 1-1.8.9-1.6 2.2-2.7 3.8-3.6 4.3-2.4 8.8-4.4 13.7-4.9.5-.1 1-.3 1.5-.5.9-.2 1.7-.4 2.6-.7 1 4.1 2 7.9 3.2 11.7zm92.2-43.3c-.1.3-.5.8-.7.9-1.8.2-3.7.3-5.1-1.3-.3-.3-.8-.6-1.2-.6-.4 0-.9.2-1.1.5-.2.2-.2.8 0 1.1 1 1.6 1.9 3.2 3.1 4.5 1.5 1.7 3.1 3 5.7 3 2.5 0 4.9 1.2 6.9 3 .7.7 1.2.7 1.9 0 2-1.9 3.4-4.1 3.4-6.9 0-2.3 1-4 2.3-5.6.2-.2.5-.4.5-.7.1-.5 0-.9-.1-1.4-.4 0-1-.1-1.3.2-.7.4-1.2 1.1-1.8 1.5-.5.3-1.2.2-1.8.2 0-.4-.1-.9 0-1.3s.3-.7.4-1.1c.1-1.1.2-2.1 0-3.2-.1-.4-.8-.6-1.2-.9-.3.4-.7.8-.8 1.3-.2.6-.2 1.4-.5 1.9-.2.4-.8.6-1.2.9-.2-.4-.6-.9-.5-1.3.1-1.7-.4-3.1-1.9-3.9-.4-.2-.9-.2-1.3-.3-.1.4-.3.9-.2 1.3.2.8.7 1.6.9 2.5.1.5-.1 1.1-.2 1.6-.5-.3-1.1-.6-1.6-1-.1-.1-.1-.3-.2-.4-1.1-1.2-1.7-3-3.4-3.5-.5-.1-1 0-1.5 0 .1.5.2 1 .4 1.4 1.2 1.9 2.7 3.7 2.5 6.1-.4.5-.3 1.1-.4 1.5z'
);
```

Code here
https://codepen.io/kylehagler/pen/VxPqyM

Comment: I won't write it as an answer because I don't like ad hoc solutions, but here it is: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJRPBR?editors=1010 Your path goes `198,541` down and right and then goes up. In the codepen I set the height and moved the M coordinates accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is 2 fold:

- first your child svg's are placed xMidYMid by default which means based on their width and height, the browser will try to re-position the viewport which will give you the impression that x and y coordinates are not respected.
- second the path you define within the child svg's viewBox 0 0 960 700 is offsetted, this means that even if you position the svg's top left corner, the path will still be offset (because it doesn't start at 0).

To remedy these, first we need to make sure we control the svg's dimensions with `preserveAspectRatio` and second we will add a translate attribute on the path to make it as close as possible to its parent's origin. So in short replace the part of your script with this below:

```
svg
  .selectAll('.fallingman')
  .data(myData)
  .enter()
  .append('svg')
  .attr('class', 'fallingman')
  .attr('viewBox', '0 0 960 700')
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio","none")//we control how the viewport is positioned
  .attr('width', '96')
  .attr("height","70")
  .attr('x', xMap)
  .attr('y', yMap)
  .append('path')
  .attr("transform","translate(-200,-250)")//move the path to origin
  .attr(
  'd',...
```